# PCSX2 1.0.0 installation issues

Tags: updates, ppa, emulation

I've followed all the tutorials I can find to get this emulator to work and I'm now getting this error. Granted I've gotten a lot further than when I started.

Running 13.10. Just downloaded the Linux download file from the pcsx2 website and did the following in terminal:

```
jonathan@Assassin:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
[sudo] password for jonathan: 
The Official pcsx2 ppa, provided by the pcsx2 team. This ppa contains a
regular package snapshot of pcsx2. We are not package experts, but we
try to follow the debian policy.

Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpe5fwdz/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpe5fwdz/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 7A617FF4 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpe5fwdz/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7A617FF4: public key "Launchpad official ppa for pcsx2 team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
jonathan@Assassin:~$ sudo apt-get update

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                 
  404  Not Found

Fetched 67.4 kB in 16s (3,977 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
jonathan@Assassin:~$ sudo apt-get install pcsx2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pcsx2
```

So I'm assuming I just need the way to get the two missing packages?

Comment: I had to edit out a lot of links that were in the Terminal but everything omitted worked fine. It's just those binary packages I think I need but not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work! Kind of an ID10T Error but I did find the saucy to raring very helpful as I did not know about that being an issue. I had it trying to install a version I didn't have. The following allowed me to download it successfully:

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*pcsx2*

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pcsx2-unstable
```

Hope this helps others! And thank you so much mmstick for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PCSX2 does not have any packages for saucy. However, you can use raring repos:

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*pcsx2*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install pcsx2-unstable -y
```

Then it should work, as the above replaces saucy with raring.

Comment: So run this in the following order and it should work?:

Comment: So I've gone in this order and I'm still unable to get it to install correctly:

sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*pcsx2*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcsx2

Error message:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pcsx2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pcsx2' has no installation candidate